# How to programmatically scale an image to the size of a ImaageButton that was created dynamically

Tags: android, image, scaling, android-imagebutton

I'm new to Android and trying to create a simple game called SoS.  It's close to complete however I can not figure out how to scale the images to put in the imagebuttons.  The game board is created during runtime, the user chooses a board size, 6 x 6, 7 x 7, or 8 x 8 (ie: a board of 36, 49 or 64 tiles(imagebuttons)).  Depending on the screen size/boardsize the images may or may not fit in the imagebuttons. So I decided to try and scale the images to the size of the ImageButton. I tried to scale the resource image to the correct size in the constructor of the Tile(imagebutton), and then store the result in a instance variable, however I get a runtime exception, and i'm not sure how to fix it.  In the scaleImages method if I change the this.getLength(), and this.getWidth() to 50 it runs with out error but no images are set in the ImageButton.  I think I need a way to determine the size of the button before I try and scale the image.

```
public class Tile extends ImageButton {
    private boolean occupied;
    private boolean isS;
    private boolean isO;
    int countClicks = 0;
    private static Drawable sImageScaled;
    private static Drawable oImageScaled;
    private static Drawable emptyImageScaled;


    public Tile(Context context) {
        super(context);

        scaleImages(context);

    }

    public Tile(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        scaleImages(context);

    }

    public Tile(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        scaleImages(context);

    }

    public void setDefaults() {
        occupied = false;
        isS = false;
        isO = false;
        this.setBackground(emptyImageScaled);
    }

    // Method will set the background image of the Tile
    // instance variable will keep track of which image is displayed and
    // will change with every click
    public void setTile() {
        ++countClicks;

        switch (countClicks) {
        case 1:
            this.setBackground(sImageScaled);
            isS = true;
            isO = false;            
            break;
        case 2:
            this.setBackground(oImageScaled);
            isO = true;
            isS = false;
        break;
    case 3:
        this.setBackground(emptyImageScaled);
        isO = false;
        isS = false;

    }

    // reset to 0
    if (countClicks == 3) {
        countClicks = countClicks % 3;
    }
}

        public void setOccupied(boolean val) {
    occupied = val;
}
private void scaleImages(Context context){

    // scale the s image
    Drawable sDr = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_simageorange);
    Bitmap sBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(sDr.getIntrinsicWidth(), sDr.getIntrinsicHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    // Scale it 
    sImageScaled = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(sBitmap, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), true));

    // scale the o image
    Drawable oDr = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_oimage);
    Bitmap oBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(oDr.getIntrinsicWidth(), oDr.getIntrinsicHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    // Scale it
    sImageScaled = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(oBitmap, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), true));

    // scale the empty image
    Drawable eDr = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tile);
    Bitmap eBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(eDr.getIntrinsicWidth(), eDr.getIntrinsicHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    // Scale it to 
    emptyImageScaled = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(eBitmap, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), true));

}
```

}

Here's the code in the Activity that creates the views and the Tiles(ImageButtons)

```
// Method adds the views to the tableview
public void showGameBoard() {

    int tilePadding = 1;
    //galaxy S4 
    int tileWH = 100;

    // Layout parameters for the TableRows
    // (Layout params are always the parent class of the object receiving
    // the param)

    TableLayout.LayoutParams rowLp = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
            (tileWH * tilePadding) * boardSize.getWidth(), tileWH
                    * tilePadding, 1.0f);

    // Layout parameters for the TableCells
    TableRow.LayoutParams cellLp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(tileWH
            * tilePadding, tileWH * tilePadding, 1.0f);

    // for every row
    for (int row = 0; row < tiles.length; row++) {
        // create a new table row
        TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
        // set the height and width of the row
        tableRow.setLayoutParams(rowLp);

        // for every column
        for (int col = 0; col < tiles[row].length; col++) {
            // add some padding to the tiles
            tiles[row][col].setPadding(tilePadding, tilePadding,
                    tilePadding, tilePadding);

            // add the tile to the table row
            tableRow.addView(tiles[row][col], cellLp);
        }

        // add the row to the board layout
        game_board.addView(tableRow);
    }

}

// Method will set up the Tiles and the listeners
public void createGameBoard() {

    // set total rows and columns based on the size of the board
    int totalRows = boardSize.getWidth();
    int totalCols = boardSize.getLength();

    // setup the tiles array
    tiles = new Tile[totalRows][totalCols];

    // for every row
    for (int row = 0; row < tiles.length; row++) {

        // for every column
        for (int col = 0; col < tiles[row].length; col++) {
            // create a tile (ImageButton)
            tiles[row][col] = new Tile(this);

            // set the tile (ImageButton) defaults
            tiles[row][col].setDefaults();

            final int curRow = row;
            final int curCol = col;
```

Well if you can solve my issue or point me in the right direction it'd be appreciated.

Comment: Can you use something like ImageButton.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER)?

Comment: please, show your error log and place where error occured

Comment: Thanks BrainCrash, I tried adding the setScaleType method in the constructor however it didn't center the image in the button.

Comment: Ok I think I figured out the problem, which is that the tileWH variable ( used to set the LayoutParameters, and the width and height of the cells) is too big and the cells are overlapping which makes it look like the images are not centered.  When I lower the value of the tileWH variable the tiles look normal

Answer (score 0):

I Don't know how your images for `ImageButton` looks like, maybe `9-patch` will help you.
[Here](http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/) is simple guide about `9-patch`. To make `9-patch` image simply, change your image's file name from `foo.png` into `foo.9.png`, open it with android studio and draw fill area and scale area appropriately. if you don't use android studio, use sdk tools in `/your_sdk_dir/toos/draw9patch`. because this is very simple tool, it needs no explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I converted the image to the 9-patch however it didn't work, and so I gave up on the images and made some new ones via http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html The new images scaled correctly.  However they are not centered in the button.  I tried putting the  ImageButton.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER) suggested by BrainCrash however that didn't solve it.  But thanks for your suggestion